# List string C# query

Tags: c#, list

I am using the List Type in C#, I was wondering what is the best way to use this if I am 100% sure that only 1 condition of the below conditions can be true at any given time. Basically I will need the output to be only on of the cities on the list, is the code below correct?

```
// List of cities we need to join
List<string> cities = new List<string>();
if(country == US)      cities.Add("New York");
if(country == India)   cities.Add("Mumbai");
if(country == Germany) cities.Add("Berlin");

string output = string(cities);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: You could have tried it, that doesn't compile.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you really need a list if it's only going to be 1 city?

Comment: using a switch case if you are sure only 1 condition will be true....

Comment: `switch` or `else if`

Comment: no, i don't necessary need a list, the switch is the best solution for me

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a Dictionary?

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"US", "New York"},
    {"India", "Mumbai"},
    {"Germany", "Berlin"},
};

// if you really want a list
List<string> output = new List<string> { d[country] }; 

// if not 
string city = d[country]

// even better
string city;
if (d.TryGetValue(country, out city))
{ } // city found 
else
{ } // city not found
```

Comment: @user2732622 I see; so my question is: Why not just use a Dictionary? It provides a clear mapping between *country* and *city*.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need a list?!?!?!?

```
var city = String.Empty;
if(country == "US")      city ="New York";
if(country == "India")   city = "Mumbai";
if(country == "Germany") city ="Berlin";

Console.WriteLine(city);
```

but honestly the code submitted doesn't compile so i doubt you spent more than 3 seconds trying to solve this on your own.

Comment: i suspected i didn't need the list type.
given only 1 if() condition can be true would it be quicker to use else if rather than if?

Comment: who cares about speed? micro optimization will only ruin good readable code. leave micro optimizations to graphics tuners and c/c++ people where cpu cycles count.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a  `switch`:

```
switch(country)
{
    case "US":
        cities.Add("New York");
        break;
    case "India":
        cities.Add("Mumbai");
        break;
    case "Germany":
        cities.Add("Berlin");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
// i assume you want to list the countries:
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", cities));
```

If you want to use `if` statements but `if`s that "exclude" each other, just use [`if-else`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (country == "US")cities.Add("New York");
else if (country == "India") cities.Add("Mumbai");
else if (country == "Germany") cities.Add("Berlin");
```

Comment: @user2732622: It is like a replacement for your `if`s. I've assumed that this is what you were after since you've mentioned that _"only 1 condition can be true at a given time"_.

Comment: @user2732622: Edited my answer to show you the `if-else` approach where the emphasis is on the `else`.

Comment: sorry for my previous stupid question, the switch is ideal for me, i have 1 more question: i don't need a list of cities but only the result of the switch in string format, how do i get that output? and do i need to declaire cities as variable?

Comment: @user2732622: If you just need a single city declare a `string` variable above the `switch`(or `if-else`) and initialize it in the `switch`(or `if-else`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [switch stament](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> The switch statement is a control statement that selects a switch
>   section to execute from a list of candidates.
>
> Each switch section contains one or more case labels and a list of one
>   or more statements. The following example shows a simple switch
>   statement that has three switch sections. Each switch section has one
>   case label, such as case 1, and a list of two statements.

So you could have something like

```
switch (country )
{
    case US:
        cities.Add("New York");
        break;
    case India:
        cities.Add("Mumbai");
        break;
    case Germany:
        cities.Add("Berlin");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch

```
switch(country) 
{
   case "US":
       //stuff
       braek;
   case "India":
       //stuff
       break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in above answers you can use `Dictionary`, `switch Case`, or `Else If`

Also i dont know when you know only one condition can be true at a time then why are you using `List`, you can use a `string` variable to store the output.